# How to silence Powershell Install Module Commands?

Tags: powershell

I have a very simple Powershell script that I am invoking from a Shell script to bootstrap an EC2 instance.

```
#user-data.ps1
#!/usr/bin/env pwsh

Install-Module -Name AWS.Tools.Installer -Force
Install-AWSToolsModule AWS.Tools.EC2 -CleanUp -Force
```

I can see the output from the Powershell script is very noisy and I want to silence these commands without hiding errors.
[image]

Redirecting to `$null` is hiding errors too and I don't want this to be hard to debug.

```
Install-Module -Name AWS.Tools.Installer -Force > $null
```

--

```
#user-data.sh
#!/bin/bash

yum install -y dos2unix
yum install -y telnet
yum install -y tree

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo | tee /etc/yum.repos.d/microsoft.repo
yum install -y powershell
pwsh /root/user-data.ps1 -NonInteractive
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even redirecting to null doesn;t hide them in normal PS, but you could try:

```
$ProgressPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
Install-Module -Name ModuleName
```

The normal value for $ProgressPreference is "Continue" if you want to change it back

Comment: Thank you. I just started using Powershell and I guess I have to get used to Preference variables like this and DebugPreference, which I found out about yesterday.